# How to Completely Exclude File from Gradle sourceSet?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

There is a file in my Android Apps `res` directory that Gradle doesn't like: "OWNERS". The file must be there, but Gradle gives the following error when compiling:

```
'O' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
```

I have tried excluding it with the following, but it makes no difference:

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs = [ 'src/main/res' ]
                exclude  '**/OWNERS'

            }
        }
    }
```

To be clear, I don't care what happens to this file as it relates to my binary - whether it gets included or not - I just want it out of the way. I don't want to replace it, modify it, or load it from a different location. I just want it gone so that Gradle stops complaining.

Why is my `exclude` directive not being obeyed?

Comment: I recommend that you delete the file. That being said, try replacing `resources` with `res` in your `main` closure.

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting the file is not an option.

Comment: Then try replacing `resources` with `res`. `resources` refers to the JDK's `resources` directory, not Android's `res` directory. I don't know whether the Android SDK toolchain will honor `exclude`, though it should.

Comment: Sadly the result is the same.

Comment: Then perhaps you should be exploring more why "I don't want to replace it, modify it, or load it from a different location" and why "deleting the file is not an option".